# Why is the empty set a manifold for all dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I was going the book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by John Lee and he says that "the empty set satisfies the definition of an n-manifold for every n". But doesn't this require a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which in turn requires it to be a bijection which is impossible?

Comment: If you want to prove that this is not correct, you will have to find a point in the empty set at which the dimension is not $n$ (for some $n$). Can you find such a point?

Comment: The definition only requires that each point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball. But the empty set has no point, so it is vacuously true that every point has such a neighborhood.

Comment: Every sentence that starts with $\forall a\in A$ will be true whenever $A$ is empty.

Comment: Every point in an empty set is a human with two heads, and has been to the Moon. Also, it has a neighborhood homeomorphic to whatever you like.